# Will reviewers see acknowledgements in double blind peer review?

Tags: publications, acknowledgement

In the acknowledgements section of a paper, I am thanking some well known people in the field I am working in, for helping me revise the paper.

Just out of curiosity: Do most conferences blank out the acknowledgements section? I feel like these people will add bias to the reviewers decision.

Comment: Conferences I usually review for, do nothing more to the submitted file than changing its name. No processing of the pdf or anything similar.

Comment: Most conferences with a double blind review that I know of explicitly instruct omitting acknowledgements in the first submission.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no reason that you need to put anything into the acknowledgements section until it is accepted and you are preparing the camera-ready version.  It is perhaps the only portion of a paper's text that can't really be affected by peer review (unless you do something remarkably unusual).  Furthermore, some acknowledgements must always be left our in order to maintain double-blind review: for example, funding should be acknowledged in the final document, but grant information breaks blinding.

Thus, I would recommend that you treat acknowledgements just like you treat author information: blank it for blind review, and add it in for the camera-ready after acceptance.

Comment: "There is no reason that you need to put anything into the acknowledgements section until it is accepted" - well, finding out how much space remains in the paper is a reason, but of course, acknowledgments can be removed (or, possibly even better, nigrified) for the blinded review version.